# Difference/subtraction of two DataFrames on numerical variables

Tags: python, dataframe, difference

I have a basic problem to do the difference of two dataframes on numeric columns. The rows are identical on other columns.

df1 :

```
     Name Sex    CA   PV  Time
0    John   M  5723  225    85
1  Andrew   M  6678  193    41
2  Gloria   F  8781  521    70
3    Paul   M  9910  502    31
```

df2 :

```
     Name Sex    CA   PV  Time
0    John   M  2082   35    60
1  Andrew   M  4567   60    18
2  Gloria   F  2676  486    52
3    Paul   M  9814  360    11
```

So, I would like to obtain the following DataFrame which is simply the difference on CA, PV and time
df3 :

```
     Name Sex    CA   PV  Time
0    John   M  3641  190    25
1  Andrew   M  2111  133    23
2  Gloria   F  6105   35    18
3    Paul   M    96  142    20
```

If you have any idea to this simply ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try subtracting the columns from one another?

Comment: Hi, doesn't work cause to string columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1.update(df1.select_dtypes('number') - df2.select_dtypes('number'),overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'angles': [0, 3, 4],
...                    'degrees': [360, 180, 360]},
...                   index=['circle', 'triangle', 'rectangle'])
>>> df
           angles  degrees
circle          0      360
triangle        3      180
rectangle       4      360

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'angles': [0, 1, 2],
...                    'degrees': [160, 90, 60]},
...                   index=['circle', 'triangle', 'rectangle'])
>>> df2
           angles  degrees
circle          0      160
triangle        1       90
rectangle       2       60

>>> df.sub(df2)
           angles  degrees
circle          0      200
triangle        2       90
rectangle       2      300
```

Comment: Thanks, but in practice I have many string columns that I can't manage as index

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [pandas.DataFrame.subtract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html)-method:

```
df3["CV", "PV", "Time"] = df1["CV", "PV", "Time"].subtract(df2["CV", "PV", "Time"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, it doesn't seem to work. Moreover, in practice I have many numerical and char variables, so I would like to find a more generic way than writing them manually.